# What are the main advantages of Knockout java script library with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

Today I was looking into Knockout JavaScript library and its features. Now I want to use this with MVC 3 applications but What is the benefits to use this with MVC 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Knockout is an [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern that works with a javascript ViewModel.  The reason this works well with MVC is that serialization to and from javascript models in JSON is very simple.

Also, it will be included in MVC4.  Here is a video by the Knockout creator on how to use it for single page applications in MVC4 (with Microsoft's new Web API feature):

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

But the benefits are really that MVVM allows you to develop rich UI's with a lot less coding (if you are familiar with Silverlight or WPF MVVM you'll know just what I mean).

Given a ViewModel of:

```
var myViewModel = { myValue: 'some text' };
```

You do not need to bind

```
$('#textBox').change(function() { myViewModel.myValue = $(this).val(); })
```

and the reverse of

```
$('#textBox').val(myViewModel.myValue)
```

all over the place, or special code handling of computed properties in your view in Knockout.  You can do it all in a very nice object oriented fashion.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myValue" />
```

And all the events are wired up.

Comment: Thanks very much Paul for prompt reply. Yes i know MVVM in WPF but still i am not able to find any specific advantage in MVC application, as suppose i have 10 properties in my model and now i have to create the same 10 properties in view Model also to bind the data. So why i do extra code ?

Comment: Immediate changes in the user interface when the data changes.  If you don't need "like-live" updates, then you don't need knockout

Comment: ok. so it means if some one do changes into my data then UI will automatically update the values without any request to server ?

Comment: You mean a change on the server? This doesn't handle changes on the servers, I mean changes in your ViewModel in other parts of your code. A good example is say you have a `span` that shows full name, and a first name and last name `input[type=text]`.  Without Knockout you need to write listeners on each text box to update the full name , with Knockout you simply need to make full name a computed property and it handles the propagation of values.

Comment: But you could just as easily update your viewmodel with a refresh from the server and have it live update, I'm just saying you need to code the client/server interactions.

Comment: Ok, got your point. This is one use of it. But when i use this script i have to write extra javascript code to create viewmodel. This is my code `<form method="post" action=""> <div id="UserSummary"> <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" name="FirstName" value="@Model.FirstName"/> </p> <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" name="LastName" value="@Model.LastName" /></p> <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p> <input type="submit" value="Update" /> </div> </form>`

Comment: Now in the above code i created 2 properties 'firstName' and 'lastName' in my javascript's view model to bind the data.

Answer (score 2):

The benifits are more structured, flexible client-side javascript code. 
You can partition better the UI and can go so far that you end up with "a-single-page-website"...
which does only do json requests (If you would like to) means less server round trips smaller responds, etc...

And for me the really cool think is the binding via observables...

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Also check this out:
MVC + Knockoutjs = Client side MVVM bliss
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2378

Answer (score 1):

The benefits are listed here - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Advantages are numerous, few outstanding features are highlighted below:

- Feasibility to connect anytime with the UI elements in data model.
- Create complex and dynamic data models with ease.
- Data binding aids in manipulating the stored data, reflecting it to the User Interface and updating the UI with regular backend changes if any.
- Supports event-driven programming model and offers 100% customization.
- Supports IE, Firefox, Safari, Bing, Chrome and many more main stream
  browsers.
- Helps in avoiding bloating up of HTTP dialogue with presentation logic and markup presentation on the server.
- It ensures application of business rules, data security and more control on the
  webpage.
- It also offers referential integrity and many validation
  features in regard to workflow for additional security.
- Knockoutjs offer outstanding extensibility. It has numerous extension points and utilities for building an application.

You can read more here from our article https://cynere.com/advantages-of-knockoutjs